# Input format for DBSCAN function in scikit-learn package

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

## Compute DBSCAN

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
```

Above is the sample code for computing DBSCAN using scikit-learn package.
My own input format is like this:
[[37.9358, -122.3478], [33.8312, -117.6053]].

The sample input format is like this:
[[ 0.84022039  1.14802236]
 [-1.15474834 -1.2041171 ]]

The way I create my own format is construct a list of list using append operation.
What is the structure of the sample format and how could I construct it?
The error message I encountered is:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Thanks!

Comment: Like all scikit models, it expects its input as a numpy array.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/85ae41c648223e697911ad4fd9f5b51a6cc465e7): a list of lists should be accepted by `DBSCAN.fit`, but it isn't, so you have to use a NumPy array (*):

```
X = np.array([[37.9358, -122.3478], [33.8312, -117.6053]])
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
```

works just fine.

(*) NumPy arrays are the preferred data format anyway; lists of lists are accepted as a convenience but will be converted internally.